# Backward compatibility when using iOS 4.0 libraries

Tags: ios, backwards-compatibility

I'm looking to use `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` for implementing a tweetie like interface for my application. (Replacing the view of a tableview cell with a custom view on detecting a swipe) However, this API was added only in version 3.2+ of iOS. I need to support all the devices running OS versions 3.0+, so I'm not sure what to do in this scenario. It seems to be a terrible waste of effort to implement the swipe detection myself when Apple has already done it (not to mention the possibility of ending up with a lower quality output), but it looks like it's a fairly common scenario. How should I handle this?

Thanks in advance,

Teja.

Comment: Actually the UISwipeGestureRecognizer class exist as an undocumented API back in <3.2, but I don't know if it's "legal" to use it for <3.2.

Comment: Hmm, just checked the docs, it says 3.2+, so I guess that should be fine.

Comment: I wonder if can get the marketshare of devices running 3.2 and lesser from somewhere. Google and Blackberry have it up on their websites, but haven't found one from Apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have quantified the problem quite accurately.

In short, you can't use it <3.2. Even if it existed as an undocumented API, Apple would reject the app for doing so.

I think you're "okay" with supporting >=3.2 as I *believe* the lion's share of people use that now - but I'm just speaking off the cuff.

We have these same issues when releasing apps under 4.0 - wanting to add stuff like Multitasking support - and cutting off 3.x users.

Apple *should* allow multiple app versions to support multiple OS versions - but - they don't!

Sorry for the bad news - but I'm in the middle of sorting out a similar issue right now, making a universal application for iPad (3.2) and iPhone (4.0) - and having to basically choose between multitasking *or* iPad support!

Comment: Ah, sucks that Apple won't let you provide multiple applications. Sorry that you have it much worse than I do, Thanks anyway!

Comment: P.S. Just for the record - my problem will shortly be rectified - in that iOS 4.2 will give multitasking support to iPads. But if what your are looking for is iOS <3.2 backward compatibility - it won't solve *that* problem...